# Order of growth of as function of N

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm practicing with algorithm complexities, I thought all the codes below were quadratic in terms of the order of growth but since I need the order of growth as a function of N, I think that changes things and I don't know exactly how to work it out.

```
int sum = 0;
    for(int n = N; n > 0; n/=2)
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum++

int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i*=2)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    sum++

int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i*=2)
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    sum++
```

Comment: No, they are not quadratic. The easiest is to run for N=10, N=100, N=1000 and watch what is the order of the sum. Then reason why it is so.

Comment: I came to a conclusion that 1. code is logarithmic, 2. and 3. linear. But again, cannot be sure.

Comment: None of them is quadric, actually.

Comment: Seems like a homework problem... First case: the external loop makes about log(N) iterations and internal loop makes about N, N/2, N/4, N/8... iterations, so finally `sum` is about 2N. Second case: the external loop makes up to floor(log(N)) iterations, so final sum is not more than 2N. The last case remains for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
    for(int n = N; n > 0; n/=2)
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum++
```

This is `O(N)`, the inner loop runs total of `N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1` times, this sum converges to `2N` when `N->infinity`, and thus it is `O(N)`.

```
int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i*=2)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    sum++
```

This is very similar to case1, and I am going to leave it to you as practice. Follow the same approach I did there, and you will get the answer.

```
int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i*=2)
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    sum++
```

Here, the main difference is the inner loop does not depend on the variable of the outer loop. This means, regardless of value of `i`, inner loop is going to repeat `N` times.

So, you need to realize how many times the outer loop will repeat, and multiply it with `N`.

I leave it as well for you as practice after explaining these guidelines.

Comment: So that makes all of them linear then.

Comment: @PRCube No, it makes (1) linear. said nothing about (2),(3) - but one of them is not linear.

Comment: you're torturing me now :)

Comment: @PRCube I want to help you learn, not hand you the answer. Give it a shot, I'm sure you'll find the answer!